# How to get a list of rows that have the same Id but different values in the same field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been playing around with different queries regarding duplicates but this is not really what I need. I do need a list of duplicates but where the value in another column is different.

I'm trying to do this in SQL Server 2012.

I need to get a list of "duplicate" rows where the DocId is the same but they have a different PoId in a table.

```
AuditId|DocMasterId|PoNumber
2224   |105        |11111
2374   |105        |11111
2574   |105        |11112
2624   |106        |232323
2874   |106        |242424
```

The query based on the above should return

105
106

But ideally, if I could list the first and last entry for each different PO based on the same DocMasterId, that would be the ideal solution, so I would end up with

```
AuditId|DocMasterId|PoNumber
2224   |105        |11111
2574   |105        |11112
2624   |106        |232323
2874   |106        |242424
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve this in SQL?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I should have clarified that I wanted to list only rows that had a PONumber set and I wanted my results sorted by DocMasterId.

Based on Tim's answer, the final result looks like this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT AuditId, DocMasterId, PoNumber,
    RN_ASC  = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DocMasterID ORDER BY 
    PoNumber ASC),
    RN_DESC = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DocMasterID ORDER BY 
    PoNumber DESC),
    CNT = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY DocMasterID)
FROM dbo.MyTable
WHERE PONumber IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT AuditId, DocMasterId, PoNumber
FROM CTE
WHERE CNT >= 2
AND (RN_ASC = 1 OR RN_DESC = 1)
ORDER BY DocMasterId
```

Comment: you can use Group by

Comment: _"where the DocId is the same .. have a different PoId"_ you haven't shown any of these columns. _"if I could list the first and last entry for each duplicate, that would be the ideal solution"_ Specify _first_ and _last_.

Comment: Also: which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: How to chose AuditId if several DocMasterId, PoNumber duplicates? (2224 or 2374?)

Comment: Hi, sorry, I've clarified the question. I'm SQL Server 2012 and ideally I want to get a list of the first PO Number and Last PO Number records for each entry that are listed under the same DocMasterId.

Comment: If you use these values  (32101,823,NULL),
(32102, 823,NULL),
(59252, 823, 'PO201300057'),
(1017082,823, 'PO201300057'),
(1017084,823, 'PO201300057'),
(1017090, 823,'PO201300057') and change the PONumber to NVARCHAR(15), you'll see that it returns one record when there should be none. Any ideas?

Comment: See beneath a piece of t-sql script to make the table and add inserts (originally I added this to the question of the OP, but that edit was rejected, so now I put it here for those interested.).

CREATE TABLE Table1a (AuditId int not null, DocMasterId int not null,
PoNumber int not null);

INSERT INTO Table1a(AuditId,
DocMasterId,
PoNumber)
VALUES
(2224,105,11111),
(2374,105,11111),
(2574,105,11112),
(2624,106,232323),
(2874,106,242424);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach uses ranking functions and a CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT AuditId, DocMasterId, PoNumber,
      RN_ASC  = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DocMasterID ORDER BY PoNumber ASC),
      RN_DESC = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DocMasterID ORDER BY PoNumber DESC),
      CNT = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY DocMasterID)
    FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT AuditId, DocMasterId, PoNumber
FROM CTE
WHERE CNT >= 2
AND (RN_ASC = 1 OR RN_DESC = 1)
ORDER BY DocMasterId
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2731f/4/0)</kbd>

---

Update according your comments that `NULL` values in `PoNumber` should be excluded and not be counted for `CNT`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT AuditId, DocMasterId, PoNumber,
      RN_ASC  = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DocMasterID 
                                   ORDER BY CASE WHEN PoNumber IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC,
                                            PoNumber ASC),
      RN_DESC = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DocMasterID ORDER BY PoNumber DESC),
      CNT = SUM(CASE WHEN PoNumber IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY DocMasterID)
    FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT AuditId, DocMasterId, PoNumber
FROM CTE
WHERE CNT >= 2
AND (RN_ASC = 1 OR RN_DESC = 1)
ORDER BY DocMasterId
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/93729/4/0)</kbd> with your sample data which correctly doesn't return any recods.

Comment: Thanks Tim! You were bang on! I've had to modify the query a bit as I forgot to mention that my PONumber were not null and it had to be sorted by DocMasterId, but once changed, it worked a charm!! I'll post my update query in a second.

Comment: We've just ran this query on a live database and the results returned are incorrect. Some of our PONumbers are null but it seems to still include them as changed value. Any idea how we can exclude these from the query? I thought the query I updated above would have done the trick but it doesn't appear so.

Comment: @Thierry: your query seems to be correct. There should be no records where `PONumber` is `NULL`. You can verify it by: `... SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE PONumber IS NULL` which doesn't yield any records. Maybe those values are `NULL`(the `varchar` value) or simply empty.

Comment: can you please try these values (32101,823,NULL),
(32102, 823,NULL),
(59252, 823, 'PO201300057'),
(1017082,823, 'PO201300057'),
(1017084,823, 'PO201300057'),
(1017090, 823,'PO201300057')
and change the PONumber to NVARCHAR(15). This returns a row when we really should get none. Strangely we've created a view to exclude all PONumber that are null and ran the query against this view and it still returned the DocMasterId 823, among many others that fall into this scenario! Very odd!

Comment: @Thierry: I'm going home now but i've still noticed issues. But maybe it helps you anyway.

Comment: you're a great gent for taking the help!! Really appreciated! I ended solving the problem by using similar to what you have. The null proved to be an issue as all audit entries started by a null for the PO Number but by excluding them as done originally and then checking the aggregate Min & Max on the PONumber within CTE and then ensuring they were different resolved the query and we manage the list we required. Many thanks once again!

Answer (score 2):

```
select AuditId, DocMasterId, PoNumber 
from ( select *,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DocMasterId, PoNumber ORDER BY DocMasterId ASC) as a from tablename ) abc 
where a =1
```

I created a partition column using DocMasterId and PoNumber which will repeat the Row_Number for every same value of DocMasterId, PoNumber. Then I eliminated duplicate records using where condition a=1

Comment: you can add some explanation?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer **Explanation:** I created a partition column using `DocMasterId` and `PoNumber` which will repeat the `Row_Number` for every same value of `DocMasterId, PoNumber`. Then I eliminated duplicate records using where condition `a=1`

Answer (score 0):

If your database supports Window function then try this

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY DocMasterId
                    ORDER BY AuditId DESC) a_rn,
                Row_number()OVER(partition BY DocMasterId
                    ORDER BY AuditId )     d_rn,
                *
         FROM   Yourtable)
SELECT AuditId,
       DocMasterId,
       PoNumber
FROM   cte
WHERE  a_rn = 1 or D_rn =1
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply `GROUP BY`?

```
select min(AuditId), DocMasterId, PoNumber
from tablename
group by DocMasterId, PoNumber
```